# How to access value from Datepicker to change button title according to date picker value?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, datepicker, uibutton

I am working on project in which I have to set button title by According to datepicker value.

My design is like below

[image: THIS]

Now my code is like below

This is button which I set into tableviewCell

```
  let btn_start_time = cell.viewWithTag(2) as! UIButton
  btn_start_time.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnStartTimePressed), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

This is my button action method when I clicked

```
func btnStartTimePressed(sender: UIButton!)  {
        let buttonPosition = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.tbl_availability)
        let indexPath = self.tbl_availability.indexPathForRowAtPoint(buttonPosition)
        UtilityHandler.addpopupZoomAnimationTopickerView(view_time_picker, view: self.view)
        time_picker.addTarget(self, action: Selector(datepickeractionmethod(time_picker)), forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
        sender.setTitleColor(BUTTON_BLACK_COLOR_222222, forState: .Normal)
        sender.setTitle(strDate as String, forState: .Normal)   
}
```

This is my datepicker Action method

```
 func datepickeractionmethod(sender : UIDatePicker) {
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
        strDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(self.time_picker.date)
 }
```

I want to change button title when datepicker value is changed.

I tried
1) I take extra parameter as button into datepicker action method and set title there but it also changed when I clicked on button , NOT WHEN MY DATEPICKER VALUES CHANGE
2) I try to set into button action method but it worked when I clicked on button.

Please help me with it.

Comment: Are you having multiple button like this in tableView?

Comment: @NiravD yes I have 2 button for setting value of date picker. For each button I open datepicker and want to set value of datepicker

Comment: Inside the same cell? or in different cell?

Comment: Same cell 2 buttons, Wait I will upload screenshot of my design

Comment: @NiravD check out design

Comment: Use textfields in the place of buttons and set the input view of textfield to date picker and update the text in the text field

Comment: are you have only two buttons in tableview ? or user can add more button ?

Comment: You can retrieve your cell by its index path. I will suggest you to declare a `NSIndexPath` instance in `.h` file. Set indexPath.row as tag on button. When you tap on button, get the tag , create a NSIndexPath instance and assign it to the instance which you declared in `.h` file. On date picker action get the cell. Get your button from cell and set the title.

Comment: you should use custom delegate to set value from viewcontroller to tableviewcell

Comment: @NiravD I will try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make one enum and make its instance to check which picker is currently shown is it startTime or endTime, also create two String instance for holding the values from picker.

```
enum TimeType {
    case StartTime
    case EndTime
}

var timeType: TimeType?
var startTime = "Start Time"
var endTime = "End Time"
```

Now use this two strings object in `cellForRowAt indexPath`.

```
let btn_start_time = cell.viewWithTag(2) as! UIButton
btn_start_time.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnStartTimePressed), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
btn_start_time.setTitle(startTime, for: .normal)

let btn_start_time = cell.viewWithTag(3) as! UIButton
btn_start_time.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnEndTimePressed), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
btn_start_time.setTitle(endTime, for: .normal)
```

Now set the enum instance in the button action.

```
func btnStartTimePressed(sender: UIButton!)  {
   UtilityHandler.addpopupZoomAnimationTopickerView(view_time_picker, view: self.view)
    time_picker.addTarget(self, action:#selector(datepickeractionmethod(_:)), forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)

    //Set which picker is Shown
    timeType = .StartTime
}

func btnEndTimePressed(sender: UIButton!)  {
    let buttonPosition = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.tbl_availability)
    let indexPath = self.tbl_availability.indexPathForRowAtPoint(buttonPosition)
    UtilityHandler.addpopupZoomAnimationTopickerView(view_time_picker, view: self.view)
    time_picker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(datepickeractionmethod(_:)), forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)

    //Set which picker is Shown
    timeType = .EndTime
}
```

Now use this enum in datePicker action

```
func datepickeractionmethod(sender : UIDatePicker) {
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
    let time = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(self.time_picker.date)
    if self.timeType = .StartTime {
        self.startTime = time
    }
    else {
        self. endTime = time
    }

    //Now simply reload tableView or you can even reload single row that contains these two buttons.
    self.tableView.reloadData() 
}
```

Comment: It is showing error into self.timeType = . Starttime

Comment: Wait i am checking

Comment: Yeah its working, but All rows value changed. Now How can I solve it?

Comment: What do you mean by "All rows value changed", Please add the whole `cellForRowAtIndexPath` that will give more idea what you are doing.

Comment: Means When I clicked on row 1 and changed value into datepicker then all rows r updated with that value

Comment: @Jecky That because of your `cellForRowAt` can you show me your whole `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128796/discussion-between-jecky-and-nirav-d).

Comment: Are you showing multiple start time and endTime in tableView with label than you must have array of time, and you need to show the selected time to just buttons not label.

Answer (score 0):

you need declare global button instance for track click button .

```
class ViewController: UIViewController{
    var clickedButton : UIButton

func btnStartTimePressed(sender: UIButton!)  {
        let buttonPosition = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.tbl_availability)
        let indexPath = self.tbl_availability.indexPathForRowAtPoint(buttonPosition)
        UtilityHandler.addpopupZoomAnimationTopickerView(view_time_picker, view: self.view)
        time_picker.addTarget(self, action: Selector(datepickeractionmethod(time_picker)), forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
        sender.setTitleColor(BUTTON_BLACK_COLOR_222222, forState: .Normal)
        clickedButton = sender
}

 func datepickeractionmethod(sender : UIDatePicker) {
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
        strDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(self.time_picker.date)
        clickedButton.setTitle(strDate as String, forState: .Normal)
 }
```